# R: How do I get rid of a question mark block in a character string?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, special-characters, naming

I have a `vector` with a bunch of `Company Name` observations that came from a separate `data frame`. I was using the `vector` as a way to look at a list of all of the unique company names in the `data frame`, then cleaning it (correcting misspellings, changing/removing names from mergers, etc.). The renaming is done line by line (i.e. hard-coded) due to the nature of the `data` not allowing for a silky-smooth cleaning process. I have run into a strange problem I'm not sure how to fix.

There were a few companies whose names involved certain special characters, like 'ñ', 'ü', 'é', etc. Looking at this `vector` from the `View` window, those observations also had an identical entry next to them, except with a strange question mark block in place of those letters. For example:

```
Company_Name

SES (Société Européenne des Satellites (SES))
SES (Soci�t� Europ�enne des Satellites (SES))
```

Initially, I fixed misspellings with a line of code like this:

```
dataframe$Company_Name[which(dataframe$Company_Name == "SES (Société Européenne des Satellites (SES))" | dataframe$Company_Name == "SES (Soci\xe9t\xe9 Europ\xe9enne des Satellites (SES))"] <- "SES S.A."
```

The alternative name you see after the name with the accented 'e's is the name with the question mark blocks. I got that alternative name by calling the specific line of the vector that the question-blocked name came up on (i.e. `vector[32]` ), and physically copying and pasting the output into the code.

Ideally, the `vector` would end up looking like this once the clean had finished:

```
Company_Name

SES S.A.
```

However, instead of removing the question mark blocks, it keeps them:

```
Company_Name

SES S.A.
SES (Soci�t� Europ�enne des Satellites (SES))
```

Has anyone else ran into a similar problem? I've checked if the problem was in the spelling, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(Note: I have no preferences for specific packages - all options are on the table!)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably an Encoding problem.

Look at the Encoding of the rows with question mark :

```
Encoding(Company_Name)
```

For french sentences, you should set the encoding as follows :

```
Encoding(Company_Name)<-'latin1'
```

Comment: @Gordon L., I would be interested to know if this solved the problem